# Архитектура MVP и Firebase/Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, mvp, firestore

**Суть:**

Использую в своем приложении архитектуру MVP. На ранних этапах разработки не было готового backend'а и использовались статичные списки/объекты, которые передавались в `Presenter` через `return` из `Model`. После этого было решено перейти на Firestore. В этот момент вся "архитектура" сломалась, т.к. `Model` перестал быть нужен - остались лишь пустые классы от него. Конечно, они еще могут пригодиться в будущем, но факт того, что его задачи стал выполнять `Presenter` мне не нравится.

Приложу ниже примеры классов из предыдущего вопроса для прояснения ситуации

Fragment:

```
public class ActionsFragment extends Fragment implements ActionsFragmentBase {

    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private ActionsPresenter presenter;
    private ActionsRecyclerAdapter actionsAdapter;
    private int state;
    private int type;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        presenter = new ActionsPresenter(this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actions, container, false);

        type = this.getArguments().getInt("type");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        presenter.notifyFragmentStarted(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        presenter.removeRegistration();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        presenter.removeRegistration();
    }

    public void handleListUpdate(DocumentChange.Type type, int newIndex, int oldIndex, Action action) {
        if (actionsAdapter != null) {
            switch (type) {
                case ADDED:
                    actionsAdapter.addItem(newIndex, action);
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    actionsAdapter.updateItem(oldIndex, newIndex, action);
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    actionsAdapter.removeItem(oldIndex);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isListEmpty() {
        return actionsAdapter == null || actionsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0;
    }

    public boolean isAdapterExists() {
        return actionsAdapter != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        actionsAdapter = null;
        unbinder.unbind();
        presenter.destroy();
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
public class ActionsPresenter {
    private ActionsFragmentBase fragment;
    private ActionsModel model;

    private Query actionsQuery;
    private ListenerRegistration actionsRegistration;

    public ActionsPresenter(ActionsFragmentBase fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.model = new ActionsModel();
    }

    public void notifyFragmentStarted(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            /* Выбор Query в зависимости от type */
        }

        setRegistration(type);
    }

    private void notifyViewCreated(int state) {
        fragment.showRequiredViews();

        switch (state) {
            /* Показ необходимых View в зависимости от состояния */
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setRegistration(int type) {
        actionsRegistration = actionsQuery.addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshots, e) -> {
            if (e == null) {
                for (DocumentChange dc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = dc.getDocument();
                    Action action;

                    /* Получение объекта Action в зависимости от type*/

                    if (fragment != null) {
                        if (!fragment.isAdapterExists() && fragment.isListEmpty()) {
                            fragment.setupLayouts(true, true);
                            notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_CONTENT);
                        }

                        fragment.handleListUpdate(dc.getType(), dc.getNewIndex(), dc.getOldIndex(), action);
                    }
                }

                if (fragment != null && fragment.isListEmpty()) {
                    fragment.setupLayouts(true, false);
                    notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_NO_DATA);
                }
            } else {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.setupLayouts(false, false);
                    notifyViewCreated(Globals.FragmentState.STATE_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void removeRegistration() {
        actionsRegistration.remove();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        removeRegistration();
        fragment = null;
        model = null;
    }
}
```

**Проблема:**

В принципе, я уже описал ее выше, но нужно уточнить. Получается, что данные получаются в `Presenter`, который уже отправляет их во `View`. Таким образом, класс `Model` остался не у дел. Перенести их в него, получается, невозможно. В качестве архитектуры я брал такой случай:

> View <--> Presenter --> Model

Таким образом, `Model` "не знает" о существовании `Presenter`, а для выполнения realtime операций это необходимо. Единственное, что я придумал, это перенести объявление `Query` в `Model`, что является таким себе решением.

**tl;dr**

Короче говоря, требуется совет, как вписать методы Firebase/Firestore в архитектуру MVP правильным образом.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: почитайте про паттерн Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. Методы Firebase асинхронны и потому их сложно вынести в  класс Модели: приходится добавлять асинхронность в методы модели, и вводить колбеки для действий по завершению метода. Получается двойная асинхронность. И тогда задумываешься: зачем дублировать, усложнять, создавая Модель, если можно работать с Firebase из Презентера?

Оказывается, работать так, через колбеки, это верный способ (так как это инкапсуляция). Только удобнее написать интерфейс для колбеков, реализовать его в Презентере (колбеки будут выглядеть как обычные методы Презентера) и передать Презентер в модель.

Проще посмотреть в [учебном проекте на GitHub](https://github.com/saksham24/Android-Firebase-Kotlin-java-Mvp-Mvc-Mvvm-chat).